# How to restore binary serialized application settings when namespace of the object is changed?

Tags: winforms

How can I restore a binary serialized object in application settings when the namespace is changed. The application setting is mapped to an Editor object

I am using .net framework 4.5, language c#, Category: Winforms ApplicationSettings

Thanks in Advance!!!

Comment: Please be more specific about the platform, IDE, programming language etc. you are working with.

Comment: @JFMeier, I have updated the question. Thanks!